# CakePHP "Warning: Cache not configured properly"

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP and getting the following error

> Warning: Cache not configured properly. Please check Cache::config(); in APP/config/core.php in D:\PHP-SERVER\cheesecake\cake\libs\configure.php on line 663
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Route in D:\PHP-SERVER\cheesecake\app\config\routes.php on line 38
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object in D:\PHP-SERVER\cheesecake\app\config\routes.php on line 38

Any problem in the settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which *CakePHP* version are you using?

The fatal error looks like a typo. Open the file `D:\PHP-SERVER\cheesecake\app\config\routes.php` and check what there is written on line 38. It looks like there is a letter missing.

It should be something along the lines of

```
Router::connect(...[whatever your route settings are]...);
```

and I guess in your file it says (note the missing r in Router)

```
Route::connect(...);
```

Did you do what the other error message said? Check the `Cache::config` call in `app/config/core.php`. You seem to have not properly set your cache configuration.

The default call looks like

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

If you changed that post the code-piece to figure out if something is wrong..